# How to get attribute value inside a div in webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

In the following HTML i need to get the login value using Selenium Webdriver.

```
<div 
   roletitle="MD" 
   careteamrole="HOSPITALIST" 
   login="adamss" 
   isconsultctm="" 
   title="Adams Samuel" 
   style="" 
   class="assign_grid assign_grid_selected" 
   id="97">
</div>
```

I tried the following, but it failed:-

---

```
WebElement getAssigneeLoginWebElement = ieDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".assign_grid assign_grid_selected"));

sAssignedCTMLoginId = getAssigneeLoginWebElement.getAttribute("login");
```

---

---

```
sAssignedCTMLoginId = ieDriver.findElement(By.className("assign_grid assign_grid_selected")).getAttribute("login");
```

---

---

```
sAssignedCTMLoginId = ieDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='assign_grid assign_grid_selected']/@login[1]")).getText();
```

---

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
ieDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='assign_grid assign_grid_selected']")).getAttribute("login");
```

I'd also check to ensure that the locators you are using are only bringing back that one element, and not more - to check this, run the same thing using `.findElements` and verify only one single result is returned.

It is common that there are hidden elements in the HTML, and your locator may be picking them up.

Comment: Thank you Arran, I am able to get the login value using the xpath you suggested.

Comment: cssSelector() is a better mechanism than cumbersome xpath.

Comment: Makes no real difference any more providing you are testing against modern browsers. The Xpath engine is now significantly improved across the board especially amongst the Chromium browsers (eg chrome & Edge)