# How to get the span class text using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a span as below:

```
<div class="ag-cell-label">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk" title="This is a draft row. It can only be seen by you. "/>
</div>
```

I want to get the text **"glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"**. How can I do it.
The validation of the test case is to check weather asterisk is not present after clicking on save button.

Comment: <div class="ag-cell-label">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk" title="This is a draft row. It can only be seen by you. "/>
</div>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get attribute value inside a div in webdriver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17592786/how-to-get-attribute-value-inside-a-div-in-webdriver)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using `Java`, You should try as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='ag-cell-label']/span")));
String class = el.getAttribute("class");
```

Hope it will help you...:)

Comment: I've been searching for a long time for a perfect example like this! Really helped! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple case of:

1. Locate the WebElement using a suitable locator strategy (Class, CSS, XPath etc) and assign it to a new `WebElement` object.
2. Use the `.getAttribute(String arg)` method with an argument of "class" to retrieve the required class value from the `WebElement` object instantiated in the first step and assign it to a new `String` object.
3. Use the `.contains(String arg)` method with an argument of "asterisk" to determine whether the "class" attribute retrieved in the second step contains the text "asterisk".