# Get an attribute value in HTML

Tags: html, selenium, xpath

[image] Please help me on this. Refer to above image.

Comment: Instead of screenshot need to share your code here..and specify your programming language as well..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get attribute value inside a div in webdriver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17592786/how-to-get-attribute-value-inside-a-div-in-webdriver)

Answer (score 2):

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("mod-sellerRating-9"));
String dataSellerRating = element.getAttribute("data-sellerrating");
```

As above, and I would use `By.id` rather than `By.xpath`.