# Selenium get data source Url

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath

I want to take all data-source url within this html code..I am not sure how can i take this code..Can anyone help me

```
<ul class="resp-tabs-list">
<li class="resp-tab-item resp-tab-active" aria-controls="tab_item-0" role="tab">
    <a class="js-tab-list js-tab-1" data-source="https://www.adsdssas.com/property/individual/BC-2030877?isl=1" data-no="1" data-ga="0" target="iframe_1">
        <img src="/themes/centralization/images/partners-tab-logo/rentalhomes-tab-logo.png" alt="RentalHomes.com" height="20" width="auto">
    </a>
</li>

<li class="resp-tab-item" aria-controls="tab_item-1" role="tab">
    <a class="js-tab-list js-tab-1" data-source="https://www.jdoasdadadqocy.com/click-8111003-11553823?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.vrasbo.com%2Fvacation-rentals%3Fq%3DDauphin%2BIsland%252C%2BAL%252C%2BUSA&amp;utm_campaign=RENTALHOMES&amp;sid=MTUwMTE0MTI4NDIwMi41LjUwLjQzLTM&amp;label=MTUwMTE0MTI4NDIwMi41LjUwLjQzLTM&amp;ft=1" data-no="1" data-ga="0" target="iframe_1">
        <img src="/themes/centralization/images/partners-tab-logo/feed_logo_vrbo.png" alt="VRBO.Com" height="20" width="auto">
    </a>
</li>

<li class="resp-tab-item" aria-controls="tab_item-2" role="tab">
    <a class="js-tab-list js-tab-1" data-source="https://www.jdadsdoqocy.com/click-8111003-10859031?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.homeaway.com%2Fresults%2Fkeywords%3ADauphin%2BIsland%252C%2BAL%252C%2BUSA&amp;utm_campaign=RENTALHOMES&amp;sid=MTUwMTE0MTI4NDIwMi41LjUwLjQzLTM&amp;label=MTUwMTE0MTI4NDIwMi41LjUwLjQzLTM&amp;ft=1" data-no="1" data-ga="0" target="iframe_1">
        <img src="/themes/centralization/images/partners-tab-logo/feed_logo_12.png" alt="HomeAway.Com" height="20" width="auto">
    </a>
</li>

<li class="resp-tab-item" aria-controls="tab_item-3" role="tab">
    <a class="js-tab-list js-tab-1" data-source="https://www.dddoaoa.com/click-8111003-11327743?url=https://www.asdasd.com/search.do?q-destination=Dauphin+Island%2C+AL%2C+USA&amp;utm_campaign=RENTALHOMES&amp;sid=MTUwMTE0MTI4NDIwMi41LjUwLjQzLTM&amp;label=MTUwMTE0MTI4NDIwMi41LjUwLjQzLTM&amp;ft=1" data-no="1" data-ga="0" target="iframe_1">
        <img src="/themes/centralization/images/partners-tab-logo/feed_logo_14.png" alt="Hotel.Com" height="20" width="auto">
    </a>
</li>
```

Tried with this code and everything looks good now

```
for (String windows : wd.getWindowHandles()) {

        wd.switchTo().window(windows);

        if (wd.getCurrentUrl().startsWith("http://something.com")) {
            List<WebElement> url = wd.findElements(By.xpath("//li/a"));
            for(WebElement now : url)
            {
               System.out.println(now.getAttribute("data-source"));
            }
                }
        }
```

Comment: Is there any code you have attempted to write yourself that we can try and help you out with?

Comment: yes i write one code but that is my office pc..Sorry tomorrow i will add that code..Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get attribute value inside a div in webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17592786/how-to-get-attribute-value-inside-a-div-in-webdriver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to collect all the "li" webelements. Then loop through each and get the value of its data-source attribute.

```
List<WebElement> url = driver.findElements(by.xpath("//li/a"));
for(WebElement now : url)
{
   System.out.println(now.getArrtibute("data-source"));
}
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks i will try and let you know.Thank you so much